# Workflow for building incremental updates for a JavaScript project with Grunt + Git

Tags: javascript, git, sass, gruntjs

Sorry that I'm not able to define a title that brings my question to a point. But I will try to explain my problem here:

We're using Grunt in our JavaScript projects to compile Sass files to CSS and to browserify and minify our JavaScript modules.

The Sass and JavaScript sources are located in multiple folders (one per app-module) with the following folder structure:

```
src/
    styles/
        base.scss
        style.scss
    js/
        module1.js
        module2.js
        app.js
```

The Grunt tasks compiles this file into this structure:

```
dist/
    styles/
        style.css
    js/
        app.js
```

All files under `dist` are ignored by Git.

When we deploy our application, we create incremental updates which is basically a `git diff --name-only` to get a list of files that changed.

Here comes my problem: when I deploy the application, I will have to build all JavaScript and Sass files. As the compiled files are outside of Git, I have no clue which of these files have changed (compared to the latest release) or not.

The only solution that comes into my mind is adding the compiled CSS and JavaScript file to Git, too. But then we will have to struggle with merge conflicts in these files.

Any ideas or experiences how to optimize this workflow?

**Update 2017-09-19:**
I've changed the title to be more accurate as what I was searching for is a workflow to build incremental updates on a JavaScript-project that uses Grunt and Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer by @Dunno, the workflow for creating updates is now as follows:

**Incremental updates**

1. Checkout `HEAD` into temporary directory with the help of `git-archive`
2. Build the project with `grunt`
3. Checkout the Commit before `HEAD` (`HEAD^`) into temporary directory with the help of `git-archive`
4. Build the project with `grunt`
5. Compare both directories with the help of `git-diff --no-index` (which allows to compare files in directories without an index)
6. Store these differences into an archive with the help of `tar` and `gzip`, ignore all files in `src` folders

**Full updates**

1. Checkout `HEAD` into temporary directory with the help of `git-archive`
2. Build the project with `grunt`
3. Store all project files into an archive with the help of `tar` and `gzip`, ignore all files in `src` folders

The usage of `git-diff --no-index` was really the life-saver, as neither `diff` nor `rsync` were able to report changes in the way I need them.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't keep compiled files in your repository - it doesn't make any sense to do so. It only causes merge conflicts and makes a mess in commit history. You should track all neccessary source and configuration files, so that anyone can build easily from any point in history. If you do that, then your problem comes down to

```
git checkout newVersion
<build>
git checkout oldVersion
<build>
diff newBuild oldBuild
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I totally forgot about traditional `diff`. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like rsync would do the job better in an automated environment.

Comment: I've answered my own question with the working process I've done for now based on your answer ;-)